# How to restrict a Windows UWP App to be installable only on Device memory

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-store

The Windows Phone user can select the default location of installing the Apps to either **Device** or **SD Card** in the Storage settings.

Suppose my app is in the Windows Store and the user tries to install my app.

**Case 1:** The user doesn't have any SD Card in his phone. So everything goes to the Device. Perfect! This works for me.

**Case 2:** The user has SD Card but the location for App installation is set to **Device** by the user. This also works for me.

**Case 3:** The user has SD Card and the location for App installation is set to **SD Card**.This is where the problem exists!

For some reason, I want my App to be installable only on the Device's memory and not on SD Card.

**Question:** Is there something that I can add in the Package.appxManifest so that the Windows Store notifies the User that My **App can only be installed on the Device's memory and not on SD Card**. Is it possible to restrict my App installation only to Device's memory?

I have gone through many links but none of them talk on this specific use case.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now specifically done during the package upload to the store.

[App Declarations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-declarations)

> Customers can install this app to alternate drives or removable
>   storage. This box is checked by default, to allow customers to install
>   your app to removable storage media such as an SD card, or to a
>   non-system volume drive such as an external drive. If you want to
>   prevent your app from being installed to alternate drives or removable
>   storage, uncheck this box. Note that there is no option to restrict
>   installation so that an app can only be installed to removable storage
>   media. Note For Windows Phone 8.1, this was previously indicated via
>   StoreManifest.xml.

Comment: Awesome!! Looks like this will work. I will try the same and then mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the packaging options there is an option to prevent the installation on an external memory, but I don't remember exactly in which tab is found, nor how it's called.

Hope that helps.

#### Edit

Found it. You just have to check the "Prevent installation on SD cards" option from the Application tab in the manifest options.

See [this tutorial](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-8-Working-with-the-package-appxmanifest) for more informations.

Comment: I have gone through the Video/tutorial. Yes in case of Windows 8.1 I can see the "prevent installation to SD Card option". But the same option is not available when I am in the manifest of a UWP App and hence I can't check it. You can also verify this at your end.